# RxJava: Thread pool for network calls

Tags: java, multithreading, rx-java, rx-java2

I'm trying to create a mechanism for limiting the number of concurrent network requests. The idea is that I want to have a fixed thread pool of, say, 20 threads, and use that pool to only allow a maximum of 20 outgoing HTTP requests.

What i've been trying to do is:

```java
public class HttpClient {
  private final Scheduler scheduler;

  public HttpClient(int maxRequests) {
    this.scheduler = Schedulers.from(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(maxRequests));
  }

  public Single<...> request() {
    return this.httpRequest()
      .subscribeOn(this.scheduler);
  }

  // sends the http request and returns a response
  private Single<...> httpRequest() {
    return ...
  }
}
```

But this is not working. I've tried setting the `maxRequests` to just 1, sending 5 requests, and then setting a breakpoint on the server that is receiving the requests on purpose to keep the first request "stuck" there, in order to see if the other 4 wait for an available thread. But all 5 of them execute, and after a while, I just get a timeout exception on all 5 requests.

I tried using `observeOn` too, but it didn't work either.

EDIT: I also tried to implement a Semaphore logic with the following code:

```java
public HttpClient(int maxRequests) {
  this.concurrentRequestsSemaphore = new Semaphore(maxRequests, true);
}

public Single<...> request() {
  return Completable.fromAction(concurrentRequestsSemaphore::acquireUninterruptibly)
   .andThen(this.httpRequest())
   .doFinally(concurrentRequestsSemaphore::release);
}
```

Where `Semaphore` is the native Java implementation of a semaphore. This mechanic worked as expected where if the `maxRequests` was 2, and I sent 5 requests, 2 would go out and the other 3 would get stuck inside `fromAction` waiting. But this approach came with other unexpected behaviors, such as the fact that even after the 2 requests received a response, none of the other 3 were executed because the `.doFinally(concurrentRequestsSemaphore::release)` never got executed. I did some tests, and it only executed after X requests had received a response. And it was completely unpredictable what X was going to be. So there could be a semaphore of 20 permits, 20 requests would go out and get back a response, and no other would get executed because the semaphore was never released by any request.

Comment: `concurrentRequestsSemaphore::release` should be called when the http request is completed, not when `this.httpRequest()` returned.

Comment: I tried that too. I tried with this after the `.andThen()` call: `.map(request -> {
concurrentRequestsSemaphore.release();

return this.httpRequest();
}`. The same issue happened. The request didn't go right into the `map` right after it got a response

Comment: this is my advice: first write a clean, simple synchronous code, where a thread aquires a permit, takes next http parameters from a blocking queue, and starts a thread to perform synchronous http request, and which finally releases the permit, Make it work, and only then, if you still want to experience sadomaso, convert it to cryptic rxjava code.

Comment: Thank you for the advice! In case you think I'm needlessly complicating this by trying to make the semaphore logic async in RxJava, it's because my entire app is running on Vert.x. If I try to implement the logic synchronously, it'll block Vert.x's event loop, which is no good

Comment: that's what I said: use synchronous semaphore only on your own threads. You can do all the work on your own threads, or only the limiter thread which acquires the semaphore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not show the body of `private Single<...> httpRequest()`. I assume you call there some asynchronous method. Asynchronous methods occupy threads only to handle response, and when the request itself is moving to the server and back, no one thread is used. This explains why you see all 5 requests arrived at the server. 
Usually, to limit the number of activities of some kind, [java.util.concurrent.Semaphore](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html)s are used, but they limit activities by blocking a thread. Logically, since your program is asynchronous, you need to use asynchronous semaphore, but it is a rare beast.
So you have following options:

- do not limit the number of asynchronous http requests at all, as they do not take much resources anyway
- launch a special thread which aquires permits from ordinary synchronous Semaphore, and then launches asynchronous http requests. The semaphore is released when a request is fully completed
- use synchronous launch of http requests with fixed thread pool
- use asynchronous semaphore. The only implementations I know are in my library [DF4J](https://github.com/akaigoro/df4j):
  [AsyncSemaphore](https://github.com/akaigoro/df4j/blob/API-8/df4j-core/src/main/java/org/df4j/core/communicator/AsyncSemaphore.java) is an extension of the standard Semaphore and so has both synchronous and asynchronous interface, and [InpSignal](https://github.com/akaigoro/df4j/blob/API-8/df4j-core/src/main/java/org/df4j/core/port/InpSignal.java) used only in asynchronous programs. An example of [InpSignal](https://github.com/akaigoro/df4j/blob/API-8/df4j-core/src/main/java/org/df4j/core/port/InpSignal.java) usage is at [AsyncServerSocketChannel.java](https://github.com/akaigoro/df4j/blob/API-8/df4j-nio2/src/main/java/org/df4j/nio2/net/AsyncServerSocketChannel.java), where it is used to limit the number of opened client connections in an Echo Server implementation.

Comment: The reason why I want to limit the number of HTTP requests is because of overloading. We use this mechanic in a service that generates reports, and each report requires sending dozens or even hundreds of requests to another service of ours, and most of the time we keep getting timeouts because the service gets overloaded. I edited my question to show the semaphore logic i also tried to implement